# Usage of a Lambda authorizer function with the AWS WebSockets API Gateway yields error in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

We've created a Websocket API through AWS Gateway that connects to a Lambda function, but in order to authorize the connection/API-request we need to create a lambda authorizer that is hit before the Lambda function. For now, this is the only option that AWS gives to authorize requests via gateway websocket connection. Hooking up the lambda authorizer is simple, but for some reason the AWS console is reporting an error that doesn't make any sense since the authorizer is attached to the `$connect` route
[image: AWS console error from the lambda authorizer]

The authorizer has all the necessary permissions. I tried to conduct a simple sanity test and log the event that was being passed in, but the lambda authorizer is being completely ignored. Aside from the Lambda authorizer, the websocket API and Lambda function work together without any issues. There just seems to be a problem reaching the lambda authorizer.
[image]

If you have any idea why this is is happening, please let me know what we're doing wrong.

Comment: @darrenz I just put the authorizer layer in our project folder and referenced the authorizer file when needed. No need to invoke a separate lambda. This has worked without any issues.